# Does access by reference violate strict aliasing rule?

Tags: c++, strict-aliasing

I know that `int* ptr = (int*)buffer` (where `buffer` is `char*`) breaks
strict-aliasing rule.

Does this syntax `int& ref = (int&)(*buffer)` also break the rule?

I [had](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33843444/segfault-in-o3-mode) some SEGFAULTs due to violation of the strict aliasing rule, and this syntax has eliminated that. Though probably still is incorrect, is it?

Comment: I know references follow the same rules as pointers in this regard. However, I don't remember if aliasing a `char*` with an `int*` (and not the other way around) is well defined.

Comment: @5gon12eder Edited, thanks

Comment: If buffer is originally an int* converted to char* and then back to int*, this is defined with reinterpret_cast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strict aliasing rules mean that you should not dereference pointers of different types pointing to the same memory location.

Since in your posted code you never dereference, it's not possible to tell if this violates the rule without seeing all the code.

Also, aliasing to the char* type is an exception and does not violate the rule. Which means you can access a memory location containing any type by converting its pointer to char*, and dereferencing it.

To conclude:

- If `buffer` points on a memory location which contains an int, and was converted from `int*` to `char*`, this is valid. However, you should use `reinterpret_cast` for this
- If buffer points to a memory location which contains chars, dereferencing the `int* ptr` does violate the rule.
- The reference version is likely to suffer from the same problem. But the compiler has no obligation to prevent or warn you from doing this
- Don't use C style casts, use reinterpret_cast instead, and read the standard about which uses have defined behavior.

Comment: As I understood from reading on the matter, aliasing T* with char* is allowed, but the other way around is not. For example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) they say so. "However this won't work the other way: there's no assumption that your struct aliases a buffer of chars". Also for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32831329/strict-aliasing-and-writing-int-via-char) they say, that `*((*int)p) = value;` violates strict aliasing

Comment: Except if you convert int* to char* , then back to int*. This is perfectly allowed and in that case, you are effectively converting a char* to int* and dereferencing it somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 3):

This is not ok (assuming you're going to use said reference to access the value). § 3.10 [basic.lval] ¶ 10 of the C++14 standard (quoting N4140) says (emphasis mine):

> **If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undefined:**
>
> - the dynamic type of the object,
> - a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type similar (as defined in 4.4) to the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type
>     of the object,
> - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its elements or non-static data members (including, recursively, an element or non-static data member of a subaggregate
>     or contained union),
> - a type that is a (possibly cv-qualified) base class type of the dynamic type of the object,
> - a `char` or `unsigned char` type.

It doesn't matter whether you attempt to access via a pointer or a reference. For a stored object of type `char`, none of the bullet points apply to make it allowed accessing it as an `int`.

The last bullet point only says that you may alias any *other* type as `char` but not vice versa. It makes sense because a `char` is the smallest addressable unit with the weakest alignment requirements.

If you want, using a pointer is the same as using a reference except that you need to dereference explicitly in order to access the value.

Comment: For an online draft version see: [\[basic.lval\] ¶ 11](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does.

Neither C nor C++ special case accesses via pointers vs. other accesses, the strict aliasing rules apply regardless of whether you use a pointer, a reference, or any other lvalue.

If you run into trouble, the easiest solution is to use memcpy to copy the memory location into a local variable - any self-respectable compiler will completely optimise this memcpy away and only treat it as an aliasing hint (memcpy is also preferable over unions, because the union method is not as portable).

Comment: Do you recommend the `memcpy` for both C and C++?

Comment: I'm not recommending it, nor the opposite, I merely point this out as an easy and correct method. There are alternatives, for example, unions work, although some compilers in the past weren't sure about this, as would manual char-by-char copying or equivalent methods. memcpy will always work, though, and is often as efficient or more efficient than other methods.

Comment: Does anything in either the C or C++ Standard actually specify that the use of an lvalue of the form `aggregate.member` to access a member of non-character type is not considered a violation of N1570 6.5p7 (C) or N4140 3.10p10 (C++), or do the Standards treat that as a Quality of Implementation issue (recognizing that whether or not the Standard requires implementations to behave usefully when code accesses aggregate members, only a really horrid implementation would fail to do so)?